# Feynman diagrams with feynmf/feynmp - edges of diagram cropped off?

Tags: pdftex, labels, feynmf, feynman

I am trying to create Feynman diagrams with LaTeX/MetaPost and feynmp seems like the perfect package to do so. I had no problems with the tutorial and can generate the diagram itself in .eps without problems. But once I started labeling each diagram, the edges of the diagram get cropped off like this:

[image: Feynman diagram with weird size issues]

What am I doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
% feynman.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\unitlength = 1mm

\begin{fmffile}{diagram}
\gdef\P#1#2{%
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(70,20)
    \fmfi{#1}{#2}
    \def\L##1##2{\fmfiv{%
      dec.shape=circle,dec.size=3thin,
      dec.fill=1,lab.dist=5thick,
      lab=\noexpand\texttt{%
        \noexpand\scriptsize ##1}}{##2}}
    \L{sw}{sw}\L{.3[nw,,ne]}{.3[nw,ne]}
   \L{ne}{ne}\L{.7[sw,,se]}{.7[sw,se]}
  \end{fmfgraph*}}
\P{plain}{sw .. .3[nw,ne]  
 .. .7[sw,se] .. ne}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know Metapost, but it looks like you're filling the background of the text labels (`dec.fill=1`), and this (white) fill covers the lines.

Comment: Redefining `\P` is not a good idea, in my opinion. However, I get the full output with this code. Also, the two `\noexpand` commands are wrong, because they annihilate the effect of `\texttt` and of `\scriptsize`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for the suggestion; I tried replacing it will `dec.fill = 0` but the only change is that the the black dots became circles instead.

Comment: @egreg Wait, does it work for you?

Comment: @elleciel Yes, it does. As I remarked, the two `\noexpand` commands are wrong, but even with them I see the whole curve. How are you compiling the example? With `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`?

Comment: @egreg `latex feynman.tex` then `mpost diagram.mp` then `latex feynman.tex` then `dvipdfm feynman.dvi`

Comment: @elleciel Yes, with `dvipdfm` it doesn't work. Why aren't you using `pdflatex`?

Comment: @egreg It gives me `! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .1` because mpost outputs the .eps file as `diagram.1` instead. (Because I'm lazy to figure how to fix this haha...)

Comment: Try changing `\usepackage{feynmp-auto}` instead of `\usepackage{feynmp}`, which doesn't require running `mpost` (just the two `pdflatex` runs are sufficient). If you have an up-to-date TeX distribution it should work.

Comment: @elleciel In any case, adding `\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}` to your preamble will allow you to use `pdflatex`.

Comment: Interesting, that does the job of generating everything including the `diagram.mp` and `diagram.1` files but the output .pdf file is empty now.

Comment: @egreg I'll try to upvote your comments once I get to 15 score by the way.

Comment: @egreg Oh wait, it works now, I just need to do `pdflatex feynman.tex` twice with `\usepackage{feynmp-auto}`. Could you write a short answer and I will accept your solution? :)

Comment: @egreg So it works both ways, either I do (1) `\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}` in preamble then `pdflatex feynman.tex` and `mpost diagram.mp` and `pdflatex feynman.tex` OR I do (2) No need \DeclareGraphicsRule but use `\usepackage{feynmp-auto}` and then `pdflatex feynman.tex` twice. The first time it generates the `.eps` (`.1`) file and the second time it shows up on the .pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, compiling the example file with `latex` and `dvipdfm` gives the wrong result; I don't know why, but the support of EPS files within `dvipdfm` is not really good and also in other cases I had problems. For instance, when I was developing `gmp`, in order to get compatibility with XeLaTeX, that uses `xdvipdfmx` internally (which in turn is based on `dvipdfm(x)`), I resorted to convert the files output by Metapost to PDF before inclusion.

So I'd recommend using `pdflatex` for this job. The problem of including the MPS file output by Metapost is easily solved by adding

```
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
```

to your preamble. Another way, which is even better, is to use `feynmp-auto` that does two things:

1. it includes the line above
2. it avoids the need to run Metapost separately

The only thing that's needed is to run `pdflatex` twice (the second run is needed only if Feynman diagrams in the document have been changed).

Another thing to note is that the code is wrong in two respects: it's a bad idea to globally redefine `\P` just for that job, because you will incur into problems when using the normal `\P` command. You *can* redefine it locally, but it's better not doing it. The same holds for `\L`. Note also that `\noexpand` in that code is wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\unitlength = 1mm

\begin{fmffile}{diagram}
\newcommand\fdP[2]{%
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(70,20)
    \fmfi{#1}{#2}
    \newcommand\fdL[2]{\fmfiv{%
      dec.shape=circle,dec.size=3thin,
      dec.fill=1,lab.dist=5thick,
      lab=\texttt{%
        \scriptsize ##1}}{##2}}
    \fdL{sw}{sw}\fdL{.3[nw,,ne]}{.3[nw,ne]}
   \fdL{ne}{ne}\fdL{.7[sw,,se]}{.7[sw,se]}
  \end{fmfgraph*}}
\fdP{plain}{sw .. .3[nw,ne]  
 .. .7[sw,se] .. ne}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

[image]