# Shifted vpaths are cropped in feynmp

Tags: feynmp

I am trying to draw a Feynman diagram by the `feynmp` package and LaTeXiT. But shifted `vpath`s are cropped in the generated image as shown in the attached. This example was working OK with my previous Mac environment, but I do not have an access to it at the moment.

Why are they cropped? How can I fix it?

The same cropping also appears when only normal LaTeX commands are used in the terminal.

```
$ latex latexit-1.tex
$ mpost feyngraph
$ latex latexit-1.tex
$ dvipdfm latexit-1.dvi
```

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{feynmp}

\pagestyle{empty} \begin{document}\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}
  \begin{fmfgraph}(120,80)
    \fmfset{arrow_len}{10}
    \fmfstraight
    \fmfleft{i3,i1}
    \fmfright{o3,o2,o1}
    % fermions
    \fmf{phantom}{i1,v1,o1}
    \fmf{fermion,tension=0}{o2,v1,o1}
    % boson
    \fmf{boson}{v1,v3}
    % neutron
    \fmf{phantom}{i3,v3,o3}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmfi{fermion}{vpath (__i3,__v3) shifted ( 0, 0)}
    \fmfi{fermion}{vpath (__v3,__o3) shifted ( 0, 0)}
    \fmfi{fermion}{vpath (__i3,__v3) shifted ( 0,-8)}
    \fmfi{fermion}{vpath (__v3,__o3) shifted ( 0,-8)}
    \fmfi{fermion}{vpath (__i3,__v3) shifted ( 0,-16)}
    \fmfi{fermion}{vpath (__v3,__o3) shifted ( 0,-16)}
  \end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

[image: Generated Feynman Diagram]

[image]

```
$ mpost --version
MetaPost 2.00 (TeX Live 2019) (kpathsea version 6.3.1)
```

```
$ /Library/TeX/texbin/latex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019)
```

```
$ dvipdfm --version
This is xdvipdfmx Version 20190225 by the DVIPDFMx project team,
```

---

**Updated**

Suggestion by @egreg showed a different result on my Mac.
[image: With fmfframe]

Answer (score 1):

The manual warns that the diagram might overshoot the bounding box assigned from Metapost.

For this case you can use `\fmfframe` around the diagram, that allows to increase or decrease the bounding box (see the manual for details).

In the code below I also added `\fbox` around the whole construction so to be able to see when the bounding box is right.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{feynmp}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{\jobname1}
  \fbox{\fmfframe(0,0)(0,20){\begin{fmfgraph}(120,80)
    \fmfset{arrow_len}{10}
    \fmfstraight
    \fmfleft{i3,i1}
    \fmfright{o3,o2,o1}
    % fermions
    \fmf{phantom}{i1,v1,o1}
    \fmf{fermion,tension=0}{o2,v1,o1}
    % boson
    \fmf{boson}{v1,v3}
    % neutron
    \fmf{phantom}{i3,v3,o3}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmfi{fermion}{vpath (__i3,__v3) shifted ( 0, 0)}
    \fmfi{fermion}{vpath (__v3,__o3) shifted ( 0, 0)}
    \fmfi{fermion}{vpath (__i3,__v3) shifted ( 0,-8)}
    \fmfi{fermion}{vpath (__v3,__o3) shifted ( 0,-8)}
    \fmfi{fermion}{vpath (__i3,__v3) shifted ( 0,-16)}
    \fmfi{fermion}{vpath (__v3,__o3) shifted ( 0,-16)}
  \end{fmfgraph}}}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Below you can see the result with `\fbox` but without `\fmfframe`, which shows that the bounding box is not computed correctly, because of the vertical shifts.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but the output I got is different from yours. I added my results in the original post.

Comment: I added an answer myself based on the accepted answer for another post, which is also answered by you. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After more Googling, I found a post on a similar issue in XeLaTeX.

[Feynman diagrams with feynmf/feynmp - edges of diagram cropped off?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172414/feynman-diagrams-with-feynmf-feynmp-edges-of-diagram-cropped-off)

The solution is to put `\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}` and compile it with `pdflatex` instead of `latex` + `dvipdf(m)`.

[image]
[image]